# Medical imaging (PyRadiomics) with .nii.gz files

Tags: python, image, medical, nifti

I am trying to implement the package:

https://pyradiomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

It looks super simple, but they expect **.nrrd** files. 
My files are **.nii.gz.** How do I solve this?
Also, have anyone tried to apply PyRadiomics on TCIA data? if so, can I see your github or Jupyter Notebook?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have NifTI files, I believe. DWIConverter used to convert DICOM<->NifTI<->nrrd, please check https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert or Slicer

Answer (score 2):

You could turn NII into numpy array firstly and then turn it into NRRD with using:

[nrrd](https://pypi.org/project/pynrrd/) and [nibabel](https://pypi.org/project/nibabel/)

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import nrrd

# Download NII
example_filename = "image.nii.gz"
image = nib.load(example_filename)

# Turn into numpy array
array = np.array(img.dataobj)

# Save NRRD
nrrd_path_to = "image.nrrd"
nrrd.write(image_path_to, array)
```

Comment: If you do this you lose all the metadata stored in the NII file. Metadata being things that you may consider essential such as the affine matrix, the slice separations, etc. This information is lost when you transform into numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Although the examples are in .nrrd, PyRadiomics uses SimpleITK for image operations. This allows PyRadiomics to support a whole range of image formats, including .nii.gz. You don't have to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

The [DWIConverter](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) converts diffusion-weighted MR images in [DICOM](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) series into `nrrd` format for analysis in Slicer. It parses the [DICOM](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) header to extract necessary information about measurement frame, diffusion weighting directions, b-values, etc, and write out a `nrrd` image. For non-diffusion weighted [DICOM](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/) images, it loads in an entire [DICOM](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) series and writes out a single [DICOM](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) volume in a `.nhdr/.raw` pair.

So that trying to convert your **.nii.gz** inside [DICOM](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/tree/master/DWIConvert) files for the `nrrd` format is a possibility by using this tools. Also, you can look at the [SlicerDMRI](http://dmri.slicer.org/) that is a similar module.